# How does the following: arrayName[x]++; work and what does it output in the following context?

Tags: java, arrays

There is a program called `countingSort`, a segment of the code of which is listed below, which processes an array `a` of integers by counting how many of each number occurs in `a`, then assigning the elements of `a` to the result array `result` using the counts to determine their locations.

```
// returns a sorted copy of a, assuming that it contains
// only integers in the range 0 .. k-1
public static int[] countingSort(int[] a, int k)
{
    int[] counts = new int[k];
    for (int x : a)
    {
        counts[x]++;
    }
    ...
```

What I am confused about is the operation of the line `counts[x]++`. I have seen the double plus sign used as an increment, but never in this context. I would like to explain how the application `countingSort({3,7,1,3,8,2,1}, 10)` is processed, in particular, the state of the array `counts[]` after the end of the loop that is given above.

Here is the full code for context:

```
// returns a sorted copy of a, assuming that it contains
// only integers in the range 0 .. k-1
public static int[] countingSort(int[] a, int k)
{
    int[] counts = new int[k];
    for (int x : a)
        counts[x]++;
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int oldCount = counts[i];
        counts[i] = total;
        total += oldCount;
    }
    int[] result = new int[a.length];
    for (int x : a)
    {
        result[counts[x]] = x;
        counts[x]++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Again, the same line `counts[x]++` is used again in the third `for` loop.

So essentially, I have 2 questions;

**What is the function of the line `counts[x]++` and how does it work?**

**Given the application to be processed is `countingSort({3,7,1,3,8,2,1}, 10)`, what is the state of the `counts[]` array at the end of the first `for` loop?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
counts[x]++
```

is equivalent to the following

```
int i = count[x];
i++;
count[x] = i;
```

the first time count is instantiated, all items in it is 0

> Given the application to be processed is countingSort({3,7,1,3,8,2,1}, 10)

the result will be

```
[0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0] // two copies of 1 and 3, one copy of 2,7,8.
```

Answer (score 4):

`counts[x]++` will increment the number that exists at index `x` of the array `counts`.

Using this information, it should be easy to anticipate what the value after the first for loop will be.